# Symfony3.1 no handle void

Tags: symfony-3.1, php-7.1

I have one class writed on Symfony 3.1 with php 7.1 and when i decide add return type as void then symfony throw exception. Method look's like:

```
private function log(): void {
//body

}
```

> "Not found App\TestBundle\Listener\void, none returned" .

How can i set return typing void for method?

Comment: That sounds like a bug in Symfony. Are you using the latest version? Have you reported it?

Comment: Are you sure you are playing with php 7.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update php to version 7.1. That error means that you believe to work with 7.1 but you are not.